# Markup for the player

Tags: reactjs

I have a media player with the styled points on the progress bar. Here are the styles of the points

```
let stylePoint = {
        height: '9px',
        width: '9px',
        backgroundColor: item.color,
        display: display,
        position: 'absolute',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        borderRadius: '25px',
        marginTop: '-2px',
        marginLeft: '-2px',
        //zIndex: '15',
        left: left,
      };
```

What I need to do is to connect those points with lines. So, now the player looks like this
[image]

What I need to do is to connect with a line the beginning of the video with the red point and so on to the end of the video.

Comment: You need to create a demo

Comment: What demo? All I need is to connect the beginnin of the progress bar with red point, red point with green and so on. I don't need any animation effects, it has to be static lines